# Windows XP SP3 URL Namespace reservation

Tags: windows, windows-xp, acl, windows-security

I have a Windows XP SP3 machine that I'm trying to setup a URL reservation on. I'm using the httpcfg utility to try and setup the equivalent of the following **netsh** reservation:

```
netsh http add urlacl url=http://+:8080/ user=Everyone
```

I'm referencing this MSDN [article](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms733768.aspx).  What's confusing me is the required ACL parameter

```
httpcfg set urlacl /u {http://URL:Port/ | https://URL:Port/} /a ACL
```

Documentation indicates the ACL must be passed as an SDDL formatted string, I'm not very familiar with the SDDL syntax, so I'm not sure how can I get the SDDL string for Everyone.  Are there some default SDDL strings for granting full permissions to various groups?  Or do I have to generate an SDDL string manually?  Is there some alternative method of simply setting the permissions as in **netsh**?

Answer (score 1):

Make a new file (say `foo.txt`), remove all the inherited permissions, then add only 'everyone' with full control. Then using command prompt execute:

```
cacls foo.txt /s
```

The console output will then contain the SDDL ACL for the file.

Otherwise you can do this using: [UrlAclModifier.exe](http://urlreservation.codeplex.com/), which is much more usable than `httpcfg`. Be sure to run as administrator in Windows Vista+ (and Windows Server 2008+)